# Output github change log from jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins

I have a jenkins server that builds files and uploads them to sourceforge. What i would like to do is write the github change log to a txt tile and include it with the upload. This way the end user can see general info on whats changed since the last build. I've found no information on how to do this and am general a noob when it comes to jenkins. I assume i'm going to need some kind of script to handle this. What i'm looking for is an example, or information how to handle it.

Looking to output the change log in this picture to a txt file. That is the pixture is a reference of the jenkins build panel. http://puu.sh/4kh7z.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7668706/6309 should help you.

Comment: git log might actual be what i'm looking for as it outputs commit history. Only thing i got to solve about it is number of commits, and/or someway to configure by release. You know how i could create a nice formatting with it were it would go release ----- X.XXX.xx ----- then show all the changes for that version then add it to an existing log